# How to write xpath for this field?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msd67.jpg)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='QuickSearchProduct']")).sendKeys("ddd");
```

I am trying to get xpath for this field but unbale to pass any text on here. what i am missing?

Comment: Please don't post images of data - post a [mcve] as text here and don't force people answering to re-type your data from a screenshot.

Comment: Does "unable to pass text" mean that you **able to find** element but **unable to enter text**? Add more details. Add exception

Comment: You do not need xpath if you have stable id

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If the `ID` is unique in `HTML DOM`, use `id` not `xpath`.

Xpath is least preferable choice in Selenium due to not having native support in different browser.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("QuickSearchProduct")).sendKeys("ddd");
```

also put some delay to let the web element rendered fully, and then you can interact with it. Explicit waits comes handy in these cases.

Comment: Woking with driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`id`** directly.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("QuickSearchProduct").sendKeys("ddd");
```

**Xpath**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//input[@id='QuickSearchProduct']").sendKeys("ddd");
```